# Batch script to enable a disabled network adapter with different names

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10, netsh, ipconfig

I'm writing a script to revert the network settings back to default which is to switch back to DHCP on LAN and re-enable the wireless adapter. All these operations were done under the local admin rights privileges for all devices that I'm managing.

While the switching over to DHCP from static works, the script was unable to re-enable the wireless adapter and showing "No more data is available". I had did a bit of troubleshooting and found out that the disabled wireless adapter is not reflected in the `ipconfig /all` command which I have been using it to obtain the adapter name (e.g Wi-Fi, Wi-Fi 2, etc.) thus the `netsh` command gave the error due to the varible being invalid.

Here is the part of the code that's responsible for the re-enabling the wireless adapter back. I'm aware that if I were to enter the `netsh interface set interface name="Wi-Fi" admin=enabled` manually it works based on the adapter name that's taken on my test device. But however I can't hard-code the adapter name as it may not be the same for different devices. Do share if there's any other code for the first line that I might not be not aware of as I did many googling and it only came up with either for the `ipconfig` or `wmic` command. Thanks!

```
::Look for the Wi-Fi adapter name
for /f "tokens=* delims=:" %%b in ('ipconfig ^| find /i "Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi"') do set wifiadaptername=%%b
set wifiadaptername=%wifiadaptername:~21%
set wifiadaptername=%wifiadaptername:~0,-1%

::Switch on Wi-Fi
netsh interface set interface name="%wifiadaptername%" admin=enabled
```

Comment: give this a try on it's own and see how it does. `for /f "tokens=4*" %%a in ('netsh interface show interface ^| find /i "wi" ^| find /i "disabled"') do netsh interface set interface name="%%a" admin=enabled`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Thanks alot for sharing. That really helps.